# Implementing pure pursuit problem in robot navigation?

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, navigation, line-following

I would like to implement pure pursuit waypoints navigation. we know that,

**look ahead distance=look ahead gain*vehicle forward velocity**

How can I calculate look ahead velocity gain/look ahead gain?

How can I calculate velocity profile for each waypoints?

Comment: I am familiar with pure pursuit, but I don't believe I have seen your equation for look ahead distance before.  Can you post a link to a paper describing it?

Comment: @Ben  thank you very much. I wrote that line from the following  code segment:

Comment: @Ben  thank you very much. I wrote that line from a code segment. See link please: http://home.konkuk.ac.kr:8080/cms/Common/MessageBoard/ArticleFile.do?id=7776762:

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the pure pursuit algorithm is that the look ahead distance is a fixed parameter.  In this original paper [1], there is a short discussion on choosing the look ahead distance.
[image: Look ahead distance selection]

I believe you should tune this to the typical speeds of your robot and the types of paths you will be following (i.e. very curvy or straight).

[1] [Implementation of the Pure Pursuit Path Tracking Algorithm](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/coulter_r_craig_1992_1/coulter_r_craig_1992_1.pdf). R. Craig Coulter, CMU, 1992.